# css grid layout using minmax for progressively smaller right column on lower resolutions

Tags: html, css

The problem I have with the snippet below is the column on the right-hand side is too wide on smaller devices.

I have used named grid lines and `grid-template-columns` and I have used `fr` to try and weight them:

```css
  grid-template-columns:
    [full-start center-start] 1fr
    [center-end drawer-start] 6fr
    [drawer-end full-end] 5fr;
```

What probably makes sense on smaller devices is:

```css
      [full-start center-start] 1fr
      [center-end drawer-start] 9fr
      [drawer-end full-end] 2fr;
```

Is there any way to scale this column so it gets smaller in smaller devices without having to use media queries/

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: yellow;
  height: 3rem;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "head drawer"
    "main drawer";
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns:
    [full-start center-start] 1fr
    [center-end drawer-start] 6fr
    [drawer-end full-end] 5fr;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.row-1 {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  grid-column: center-end / drawer-start;
}

.main {
  border: 10px solid orange;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: center-end / drawer-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="root">
      <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row-1">Row 1</div>
        <div class="main">main</div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i understood correctly, you want a responsive **drawer**. So why you don't use margins instead of additional colums? I mean one column (1fr) with **margin-left** and **margin-right**.